# Matching specific string(s) in a mysql field

Tags: mysql

I have this simple table `foo` with only `id` and `foo_value`.In the `foo_value` field is a record with this value: `roan LOAN roann loan lloan RLOAN`.All i want to do is to know whether the `foo_value` contains the keyword `LOAN` OR `loan`.Loan or loan is acceptable.

I tried this

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_value LIKE 'loan%';`

This does not return anything?.

How should i make it tell me that that keyword is available or not?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LOWER()` function

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE LOWER(foo_value) LIKE '%loan%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE upper(foo_value) like '%LOAN%';
```

as the string in MySQL is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use '%loan%' to match the keyword in the entire string.

'loan%' returns entires that matches only with the start of the string.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_value LIKE '%loan%'
```